# What's the difference between superscripts and subscripts on fields?

Tags: linear-algebra

$P_2$ vs $\mathbb{R}^3$

$P_2$ represents the set of polynomials equal to or less than degree 2.

$\mathbb{R}^3$ represents (I think) a vector with 3 elements.

Is there any difference if the number is placed as superscript or subscription?

Comment: By the way, neither of those objects are fields themselves. They can be constructed from fields but they are only vector spaces over the fields.

Comment: Good thing that they are written differently because $P_2$ has dimension *3*.

Comment: @lhf and R3 has dim of 3, right?

Comment: @macdonjo, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are notational conventions. Sometimes they are compatible, sometimes not.

If $F$ is a field, $F^k$ denotes the vector space of $k$-tuples of elements of $F$.  Such is the case with $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Since this set also the $k$-fold Cartesian product of $F$ with itself, the superscript notation agrees with that for powers.

Other times a construction will depend on a number like degree, and it's typical to put that in the subscript.

A good author will define his or her notation at the outset, as in, "Let $P_2$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq 2$ over $\mathbb{R}$." Then there is no ambiguity.